# what is the default order for a simple SELECT in a MySQL table with AUTO_INCREMENT column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table (mytable) with an AUTO_INCREMENT column (id_mt). When I do a simple query like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

The result is ordered by the AUTO_INCREMENT column like with

```
SELECT * FROM mytable order by id_mt;
```

So my question is : what are the rules (if there are) for the result order when you don't use 'order by' AND if you have an AUTO_INCREMENT column ?

To be clear for some who refer to other posts : I don't use

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ORDER BY sort_order ASC;
```

It is clear that this query just change the performances when you use an ORDER BY query.
My question was more 'Does the AUTO_INCREMENT change (force ?) the order of a simple SELECT ?'

Comment: Normally, it depends on where the file was written.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek No this post was about default order with 'sort_order'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [DBA Stack Exchange site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6053/20509):

In the SQL world, order is not an inherent property of a set of data. Thus, you get no guarantees from your RDBMS that your data will come back in a certain order -- or even in a consistent order -- unless you query your data with an ORDER BY clause.

- So, to answer your question, MySQL sorts the records however it wants without any guarantee of consistency.
- If you are just curious about the internals of MySQL, Rolando provides an interesting answer.
- If, on the other hand, you intend to rely on this order for anything, **you must specify your desired order using `ORDER BY`. To do anything else is to set yourself up for unwelcome surprises**.

Comment: Sure, I know the theory : 'always use ORDER BY if you want ORDER BY'. I am just curious about the internal ordering, mainly when you have an AUTO_INCREMENT column.